# Method overriding error with base class as an argument

Tags: java, oop, inheritance, overriding

I have the following code:

```
interface Entity {
    
}
class Student implements Entity{
    
}
class Course implements Entity{
    
}

interface BaseRepository {
    public void save(Entity entiy);
}

class StudentRepository implements BaseRepository {
    @Override
    public void save(Student student) {
        // student validation code
        // save the entity
    }
}
class CourseRepository implements BaseRepository {
    @Override
    public void save(Course course) {
        // course validation code
        // save the entity
    }
}
```

When I try to compile it, gives me the following error:
`StudentRepository is not abstract and does not override abstract method save(Entity) in BaseRepository`

Doesn't java accept a 'Base' class as an argument? What is the reason?
Is there any alternate way to write the code?

Comment: You need generics. `BaseRepository<T extend Entity>` and `save(T entity)`.

Comment: Try to remove '@Override' tag

Comment: @Rob that could work, but you can't call `save` on a `BaseRepository` reference . And you still need to implement `save(Entity)` because the interface still declares it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An overriding method must:

- have the exact same name
- have the exact same argument types; sub types won't work!
- have a visibility that is the same or broader (so protected -> public is allowed, protected -> private isn't)
- have a return type that is the same or a sub type

You're violating the second rule here. Fortunately, you can use generics to fix this:

```
interface BaseRepository<E extends Entity> {
    public void save(E entiy);
}

class StudentRepository implements BaseRepository<Student> {
    @Override
    public void save(Student student) {
        // student validation code
        // save the entity
    }
}
class CourseRepository implements BaseRepository<Course> {
    @Override
    public void save(Course course) {
        // course validation code
        // save the entity
    }
```

}

Now, the method that a `BaseRepository<Student>` should override is not `public void save(Entity)` but `public void save(Student)`. Similarly, the method that a `BaseRepository<Course>` should override is not `public void save(Entity)` but `public void save(Course)`.